# Do EEA members benefit from EU free trade deals?

Tags: european-union, efta

Consider a country that is a member of the [EEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Economic_Area) (but not the EU) and also the [EFTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Free_Trade_Association). If the EU negotiates a zero tariff free trade deal with Costa Rica, say, do EEA/EFTA counties also benefit from this deal?

Comment: “A member of the EEA and hence the EFTA” doesn’t make sense. Of the 31 EEA states, only 3 are also EFTA members; additionally, there is Switzerland, which is a member of EFTA but not EEA. You should clarify your question.

Comment: @chirlu I took this line of reasoning from http://www.efta.int/faq and the question "Is it possible to become a party to the EEA Agreement without being a member of the EU or EFTA?"

Comment: OK, “non-EU EEA” is a meaningful term (and then also implies EFTA).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the non-EU countries won’t be able to trade under the new trade agreement, because it will (typically) only apply to goods originating in the EU or Costa Rica. The agreement will also specify [rules of origin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rules_of_origin) to define what counts as “originating in the EU”.

Indirectly, of course, they may still benefit from the agreement in that it bolsters the economy in some of their most important partners (the EU members).

Comment: I find this a little confusing. Can a business in a non-EU EEA country set up a subsidiary in the EU which then just forwards goods on to themselves, taking advantage of the free trade between their country  and the EU?

Comment: @Anush: No. Most rules of origin require a “substantial transformation” for the origin to change. Norwegian goods that are simply forwarded to Costa Rica via the Netherlands are still Norwegian, not Dutch.

Comment: Interesting. Is that the same the other way round. That is Costa Rican goods that are delivered to the Netherlands but forwarded to Norway?

Comment: @Anush: Yes, Norwegian customs will collect the duties that apply for imports from Costa Rica in that case.