# If the UK leaves the EU but joins the EEA, what happens to non-EU trade?

Tags: united-kingdom, european-union, efta

If the UK joins the EEA but leaves the EU, I understand it will have free trade with the EU via EFTA. What about trade with all the non-EU countries? I understand that the UK [would not benefit from the existing EU trade deals with other countries](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/35886/do-eea-members-benefit-from-eu-free-trade-deals/35890).  Will it default to WTO terms until it negotiates bilateral deals with each one in turn?  Does Norway, for example, have a huge list of bilateral trade deals with all the world's non-EU countries?

Comment: Some discussion currently in the UK is about a “Norway plus” model, which would combine EEA membership with a customs union with the EU

Comment: Norway’s list of free trade agreements: https://www.regjeringen.no/no/tema/naringsliv/handel/nfd---innsiktsartikler/frihandelsavtaler/norways-free-trade-agreements/id457017/ It appears all of them are shared with the other EFTA members (though Switzerland has additional agreements with Japan and China).

Comment: So maybe the UK would automatically benefit from the existing EFTA trade deals?